# How to read web header using php?

Tags: php, html

Basically we read the requesting headers using

```
       print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_MSISDN']);
             OR 
       $headers = apache_request_headers();
       print_r($headers['MSISDN']);
```

But using those code i can't receive the MSISDN number from web header.The MSISDN is send through the web header.
so,****is their any other way to read the web header?****The header formate is below.

**Example header:**

```
GET /Gamezilla/Wap/Home.aspx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: MOT-RAZRV3x/85.9B.C0R MIB/BER2.2 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1
Accept: */*, text/css, image/*;q=0.9, application/javascript, application/vbscript, application/xhtml+xml, text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ypx2scvweaahpd45gvf0ge45
x-wap-profile: "http://motorola.handango.com/phoneconfig/razrv3x/Profile/razrv3x.rdf"
X-Device-User-Agent: MOT-RAZRV3x/85.9B.C0R MIB/BER2.2 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1
APN: testint
Charging-Characteristics: 0800
Bearer-Type: GPRS
SGSN-IP-Address: 123.123.123.123
Accounting-Session-ID: 213.213.213.213:CA3806A24C452CD2
MSISDN: 00123456789
IP-Address: 213.213.213.213
NAS-IP-Address: 10.123.123.123
Via: 1.1 Bytemobile OSN WebProxy/5.2
Host: wap.abc.com
Cache-Control: max-age=43200
Connection: keep-alive
```

please help me to receive the MSISDN information from the provided header.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php.

Comment: get_headers need a url.But my requirement is when used hit on my portal then i perse his headers.so, pls suggest..how can i perse the header? also http_parse_headers and $_SERVER is not same working function? pls suggest..

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.But pls help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is installed as an Apache module, then `apache_request_headers()` should work to retrieve all HTTP headers sent with the request. In the case of `$_SERVER['HTTP_MSISDN']` not working, perhaps it is not registering as an environment variable. Perhaps you might want to consider installing PHP as an Apache module if you have access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The standard header for MSISDNs is x-up-calling-line-id. Try to change it to that value.
Also you might want to use this PHP-snippet to display all headers:

```
<?php
   $bla = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   echo "<li>REMOTE_ADDR = $bla</li>";
   foreach($_SERVER as $h=>$v)
        if(ereg('HTTP_(.+)',$h,$hp))
               echo "<li>$h = $v</li>\n";
?>
```